# How to access standard string manipulation functions in Lua?

Tags: lua

I need some basic string operations, like sub-string, find string in string etc. I found a documentation of some standard functions for that: http://www.lua.org/manual/2.4/node22.html

But when I try it, I get an error:

```
input:29: attempt to call a nil value (global 'strfind')
```

Do I have to use `require`? Or are those methods contained in some object?

Comment: That link is about very old Lua version.  See [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4) for modern Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you posted is for Lua version 2.4. The latest version as of this post is Lua version 5.3. Make sure you are viewing the documentation for the version of Lua that you are using.

[Lua 5.3 Reference](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/index.html#contents)